# Why users counts differ between Home and Audience-overview in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Examples like below: 
[google analytics-home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssr4P.png)

[google analyics-audience overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoDrY.png)

Does google use different queries to show each graph?

Answer (score 0):

The data to be stable in Google Analytics require at least 48h.

Try to see if the problem is also with the previous days.

Then try tomorrow (after 48h) to see if the data for May 12 has aligned.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
In case of Google Demo Account, the data after 48h has aligned pretty well.

Comment: But the data from my clients property has not aligned even after 48h. 

Is there anything that could be causing the problem? the data from some clients has aligned well, the data from the others has not aligned. the only difference that I found was amount of data. when clients have large amount of data, the graph differed between google-analytics home and google-analytics audience-overview.